# When has my laptop been put to sleep? When has it been awakened?

Tags: linux, suspend

The title says it all... I can add that I'd like to access the full history, full meaning at least to the last time I turned off my computer.

I have a Debian Sid laptop and a Suse Tumbleweed one, so both are controlled by Systemd, if this matters.

---

*Final Consideration/Confession*

I was asking because I wanted to approximate how much I slept yesterday, Sat 27.

```
Jan 27 00:58:30 localhost.localdomain kernel: PM: suspend entry (deep)
Jan 27 12:08:13 localhost.localdomain kernel: PM: suspend exit
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sleep and resume states are logged by the kernel:

```
% journalctl -kg '^PM:.*suspend' 
Jan 27 03:01:21 roujiamo kernel: PM: suspend entry (deep)
Jan 27 16:36:11 roujiamo kernel: PM: suspend exit
```

You can also get these via dmesg, but the times there are converted on the fly from uptime time to realtime and thus may be inaccurate across sleep periods depending on your hardware. `journald` is generally more accurate.

You can also get these through history, instead of just on the last boot:

```
% journalctl -g '^PM:.*suspend' _TRANSPORT=kernel | tail -20
Jan 23 17:38:05 roujiamo kernel: PM: suspend entry (deep)
Jan 23 19:51:00 roujiamo kernel: PM: suspend exit
Jan 24 04:48:20 roujiamo kernel: PM: suspend entry (deep)
Jan 24 14:18:28 roujiamo kernel: PM: suspend exit
Jan 24 20:04:23 roujiamo kernel: PM: suspend entry (deep)
Jan 24 23:31:17 roujiamo kernel: PM: suspend exit
Jan 25 01:34:08 roujiamo kernel: PM: suspend entry (deep)
Jan 25 02:12:58 roujiamo kernel: PM: suspend exit
Jan 25 02:14:30 roujiamo kernel: PM: suspend entry (deep)
Jan 25 13:02:19 roujiamo kernel: PM: suspend exit
Jan 25 15:36:25 roujiamo kernel: PM: suspend entry (deep)
Jan 25 16:15:36 roujiamo kernel: PM: suspend exit
-- Boot 63ab749cdfd84d7c85fd0555afed54e4 --
Jan 25 18:04:34 roujiamo kernel: PM: suspend entry (deep)
Jan 25 22:37:18 roujiamo kernel: PM: suspend exit
-- Boot 1f0c9c311ded429bbac7d69fc7d7aea9 --
Jan 27 03:01:21 roujiamo kernel: PM: suspend entry (deep)
Jan 27 16:36:11 roujiamo kernel: PM: suspend exit
```

Comment: Is "`% `" the shell prompt for `root`? Maybe you want to edit your answer to have "`$ sudo ` in its place, but your answer is however one-plussed and accepted, ty.

Comment: The events are logged by `journald` in local time.

Comment: @gboffi You don't need root, just the appropriate journal reading permissions.